# How to refresh a basic "database" with .json files

Tags: java, json, database, list

I'm working on a University project written in Java. The project consist on a little software for a chain of sporting goods stores. My teacher told me to save the staff information, the sport objects and many other things (shop orders,...) into JSON files, using JSON simple.jar. 
My software at the beginning load lists from .json files, here is an example:

```
private static ArrayList<Person> personale = new ArrayList<Person>();
public ArrayList<Person> readPersonale() throws IOException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("f:\\personale.json");
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fileReader);
    ArrayList<Person> personale = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("personale");
    for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
        Person p = new Person();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject)array.get(i);
        p.setName(json.get("NAME"));
        p.setSurname(json.get("SURNAME"));
        p.setUserCode(json.get("USER CODE"));
        p.setPassword(json.get("PASSWORD"));
        p.setRule(json.get("RULE"));
        personale.add(p);
    }
    fileReader.close();
    return personale;
}
```

Before software's closing, my program has to delete the content of previous .json files and rewrite all the lists into the same .json file:

```
    public void writePersonale(ArrayList<Person> list) throws org.json.simple.parser.ParseException, ParseException {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray Jlist = new JSONArray();
    for(Person e : list) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("NAME", e.getName());
        json.put("SURNAME", e.getSurname());
        json.put("USER CODE", e.getUserCode());
        json.put("PASSWORD", e.getPassword());
        json.put("RULE", e.getRule());
        Jlist.add(json);
    }
    obj.put("personale", Jlist);

    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("f:\\personale.json")) {
        file.write(obj.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to program with .json files? There is a better way to use the jSON files?
Thanks

Comment: Is it imperative that you use the library you mention or can you use anything else?

Comment: @Aris no, I can use anything, There aren’t limitations

Comment: OK gimme some time to post another approach.

Comment: Also would it be possible to post a sample JSON of your users?

Comment: @Aris it is very simple, There are only strings name, surname, rule, usercode, password

Comment: FYI: Some databases such a Postgres provide a bulk-data loading feature to rapidly import simple tab-delimited or comma-separated text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first of all I would avoid using the library you're using for JSON processing. Manually creating JSONArrays etc etc is more of a pain in the ass rather than something productive. In that sense I would go with `Jackson` to perform any serialization/deserialization (writing to and from the db).

Since `Jackson` can actively map datatypes and convert them you will the following POJOs to do your job:

UserDto

```
public class UserDto {

    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    private String surName;
    public String getSurName() { return surName; }
    public void setSurName(String surName) { this.surName = surName; }

    private Integer userCode;
    public Integer getUserCode() { return userCode; }
    public void setUserCode(Integer userCode) { this.userCode = userCode; }

    private String rule;
    public String getRule() { return rule; }
    public void setRule(String rule) { this.rule = rule; }

    public UserDto() {}

    public UserDto(String name, String surName, Integer userCode, String rule) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surName = surName;
        this.userCode = userCode;
        this.rule = rule;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserDto{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", surName='" + surName + '\'' +
            ", userCode=" + userCode +
            ", rule='" + rule + '\'' +
            '}';
    }

}
```

BulkUserDto

```
public class BulkUserDto {

    private List<UserDto> userDtos;
    public List<UserDto> getUserDtos() { return userDtos; }
    public void setUserDtos(List<UserDto> userDtos) { this.userDtos = userDtos; }

}
```

With those two in place your database utility class can be simplified to this:

```
public final class DatabaseUtil {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "/tmp/db.json";

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private DatabaseUtil() {}

    public static List<UserDto> initUserList() throws IOException {
        BulkUserDto dto = objectMapper.readValue(Paths.get(FILE_PATH).toFile(), BulkUserDto.class);
        return dto.getUserDtos();
    }

    public static void saveUserList(BulkUserDto dto) throws IOException {
        String parsedObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dto);
        if (Files.exists(Paths.get(FILE_PATH))) {
            System.out.println("Found old db file under:: " + FILE_PATH + " deleting");
            Files.delete(Paths.get(FILE_PATH));
        }

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(Paths.get(FILE_PATH).toFile());
        writer.write(parsedObject);
        writer.flush();
    }

}
```

Note that how streamlined is the serialization/deserialization process this. For more on Jackson you can consult the following basic tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Note also that the saving method actively checks and deletes the old db.json file if it is already present in the filesystem.

Another nice optimization you could potentially do is the following. Since you store all the read User entries in a static list, you're effectively creating a cache. I assume you call `readPersonale` only once through the program otherwise and since it appear that you have no related checks in place, this would corrupt it. Based on the above I would suggest the following:

I would leave the static list declaration but instead of assigning it an empty list I would go ahead and leave it null. I would then create the following method to make sure that the cache is initialized only once:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static List<UserDto> userCache;
    public static List<UserDto> getUserCache() {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (userCache == null) {
                try {
                    userCache = initUserList();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
            }
            return userCache;
        }
    }
```

Note here the synchronized block which will make sure that initialization will happen only once and only by the first calling thread.

With this in place I would simple uses this cache to add/remove user and then finally I would just go ahead and save this. Note that if you do choose to follow this, you should take synchronization into account (assuming that you have more than one threads in you program).